# What is UG-hardness, and how is it different from NP-hardness based on the unique games conjecture?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, approximation-hardness, unique-games-conjecture

There are many inapproximability results which rely on the unique games conjecture.  For example,

> Assuming the unique games conjecture, it is NP-hard to approximate the maximum cut problem within a factor *R* for any constant *R* > *R*<sub>GW</sub>.

(Here *R*<sub>GW</sub> = 0.878… is the approximation ratio of the Goemans–Williamson algorithm.)

However, some people prefer to use the term “[UG-hard](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2005/12/ug-hard.html)” as:

> It is UG-hard to approximate the maximum cut problem within a factor *R* for any constant *R* > *R*<sub>GW</sub>.

Is the latter just a shorthand for the former, or do they mean different statements?

Comment: +1 Very Nice. Thanks Tsuyoshi for shedding light on this important concept in complexity theory.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*An earlier version of this answer was originally posted as an answer to the question “[Consequences of Unique Games being a NPI problem](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11662/consequences-of-unique-games-being-a-npi-problem)” by NicosM.  Because it turned out that it did not answer what he wanted to ask, I moved it to this question.*

Short answer: They mean different statements.  The latter implies the former, but the former does not necessarily imply the latter.

Long answer: Recall that the unique game problem is the following promise problem.

**Unique game problem with parameters *k*∈ℕ and *ε*, *δ* > 0 (1−*ε* > *δ*)**
*Instance*: A two-player one-round unique game *G* with label size *k*.
*Yes-promise*: *G* has value at least 1−*ε*.
*No-promise*: *G* has value at most *δ*.

The unique games conjecture states:

> **Unique games conjecture.**  For all constants *ε* and *δ*, there exists a constant *k* such that the unique game problem with parameters *k*, *ε*, and *δ* is NP-complete.

Consider results of the following form:

> (1) Assuming the unique games conjecture, problem *X* is NP-hard.

(An example of *X* is the problem of approximating maximum cut within some constant factor *R* > *R*<sub>GW</sub>.)

Most (if not all) of the results of the form (1) actually prove the following fact:

> (2) There exist constants *ε* and *δ* such that for every constant *k*, the unique game problem with parameters *k*, *ε*, and *δ* is reducible to *X*.

It is easy to verify that (2) implies (1).  However, (2) implies more than (1): for example, suppose that one day we can prove that a variant of the unique games conjecture where “NP-complete” is replaced with “[GI](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo:G#gi)-hard.”  Then (2) implies that *X* is also GI-hard.  (1) does not imply this.  This is why some people consider that statement (1) is not the best way to state the theorem: (1) is weaker than what is actually proved, and the difference might be important.

Although (2) is a more accurate statement of what is proved, it is clearly mouthful.  This is why people have come up with a shorthand for it: “Problem *X* is UG-hard” is a shorthand for (2).

Comment: This seems analogous to the two statements: "(1) Assuming P != NP, X has no polynomial time algorithm" and "(2) X is NP-hard." (2) implies (1), but (1) doesn't imply (2). In practice, we usually prove (2), although we often say (1) to explain the significance of the proof to people unfamiliar with NP-hardness.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto you might consider accepting your own answer :). It's actually encouraged, and this is a good reference q/a for future googlers.

Comment: @Suresh: Thanks.  I probably will, but the system requires me to wait 48 hours after posting the question before accepting my own answer.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Ah I didn't realize that. sounds good.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: nice clear answer! sorry I didn't follow up on your request to make my comments an answer to the other question: I was party busy, part lazy, part didn't feel that the revised question was a question at all.

Comment: @Sasho: Thanks, and no problem. I just wanted to tell you before I actually moved my answer so that you had a chance to post your comment as a separate answer if you wanted to, but I understand all the reasons you mentioned.  (I am not claiming that you are lazy. :))